# Converting Pine Script from v2 to v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I found an indicator, which is probably older (written in v2) and I'm trying to convert it to v5, but I'm still getting errors.
Here's the v2 version:

```
study(title = "Smoothed Heiken Ashi Candles", shorttitle="Smoothed Ha Candles", overlay=true)

len=input(10)
o=ema(open,len)
c=ema(close,len)
h=ema(high,len)
l=ema(low,len)

haclose = (o+h+l+c)/4
haopen = na(haopen[1]) ? (o + c)/2 : (haopen[1] + haclose[1]) / 2
haopen = na(haopen[1]) ? (o2 + c2) / 2 : (haopen[1] + haclose[1]) / 2
hahigh = max (h, max(haopen,haclose))
halow = min (l, min(haopen,haclose))

len2=input(10)
o2=ema(haopen, len2)
c2=ema(haclose, len2)
h2=ema(hahigh, len2)
l2=ema(halow, len2)

col=o2>c2 ? red : lime
plotcandle(o2, h2, l2, c2, title="heikin smoothed", color=col)
```

Here's what I did so far in v5:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title = "Smoothed Heiken Ashi Candles", shorttitle="Smoothed Ha Candles", overlay=true)
import TradingView/ta/5

len=input(10)
o=ta.ema(open,len)
c=ta.ema(close,len)
h=ta.ema(high,len)
l=ta.ema(low,len)

haclose = (o+h+l+c)/4
haopen = na(haopen[1]) ? (o + c)/2 : (haopen[1] + haclose[1]) / 2
hahigh = math.max (h, math.max(haopen,haclose))
halow = math.min (l, math.min(haopen,haclose))

len2=input(10)
o2=ta.ema(haopen, len2)
c2=ta.ema(haclose, len2)
h2=ta.ema(hahigh, len2)
l2=ta.ema(halow, len2)

col=o2>c2 ? color.red : color.lime
plotcandle(o2, h2, l2, c2, title="Smoothed HA", color=col)
```

The error I'm getting now is: Undeclared identifier 'haopen'. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator(title = "Smoothed Heiken Ashi Candles", shorttitle="Smoothed Ha Candles", overlay=true)
import TradingView/ta/5

len=input(10)
o=ta.ema(open,len)
c=ta.ema(close,len)
h=ta.ema(high,len)
l=ta.ema(low,len)

haclose = (o+h+l+c)/4 
haopen=0.0 
haopen := na(haopen[1]) ? (o + c)/2 : (haopen[1] + haclose[1]) / 2
hahigh = math.max (h, math.max(haopen,haclose))
halow = math.min (l, math.min(haopen,haclose))

len2=input(10)
o2=ta.ema(haopen, len2)
c2=ta.ema(haclose, len2)
h2=ta.ema(hahigh, len2)
l2=ta.ema(halow, len2)

col=o2>c2 ? color.red : color.lime
plotcandle(o2, h2, l2, c2, title="Smoothed HA", color=col)
```

Comment: Many thanks! So, had to initialize the variable first. And I'll have to study what's the difference between "=" and ":=".

Comment: Can you highlight what you changed here and explain why?